# find files grep result then sort by file datetime modification

Tags: 18.04, bash, grep, find, sort

I have the following files

```
**file_01.sh**  
abc  
bla bla function pause(){ 
bla
foo function juliet(){ 
foo


**file_02.sh**  
abc  
bla bla function pause(){ 
bla
bla bla jjdjdjd
foo function charlie(){ 
foo
bla bla function mike(){ 
bau


**file_03.sh**  
abc  
bla bla function pause(){ 
bla
bau


**file_04.sh**  
abc
def
bl bl function foxtrot(){ 
bla
bau


**file_05.sh**  
abc
def
ghi
bl bl function foxtrot(){ 
bla
bau
```

this is the result i WISH to have :
(sorted by "file modification date-time-stamp"
with more recent files on the top) :

```
2020/12/25    18:33:04   ./i_dir/file_04.sh:     3:bl bl function foxtrot(){ 
2020/12/25    18:33:02   ./i_dir/file_05.sh:     4:bl bl function foxtrot(){ 
2020/12/25    18:33:00   ./i_dir/file_01.sh:     4:foo function juliet(){ 
2020/12/25    18:32:56   ./i_dir/file_02.sh:     5:foo function charlie(){ 
2020/12/24    18:32:58   ./i_dir/file_02.sh:     7:bla bla function mike(){
```

This is what I try so far.

command 01:

```
pattern_GOOD_word="(function\s){1}"
pattern_BAD_word="(function\spause){1}"

$ find "i_dir" -type f -iname "*.sh" \
 -exec grep -E -i "$pattern_GOOD_word" {} \; \
 | grep -E -v  "$pattern_BAD_word" >> "o_file_01.txt"
```

result 01:

```
**“o_file_01.txt”:**
./i_dir/file_01.sh:4:foo function juliet(){  
./i_dir/file_02.sh:5:foo function charlie(){ 
./i_dir/file_02.sh:7:foo function foxtrot(){
./i_dir/file_04.sh:3:bl bl function foxtrot(){  
./i_dir/file_05.sh:4:bl bl function foxtrot(){
```

but i need each line to have datetime stamp information like this :

```
2020/12/25    18:33:04   ./i_dir/file_04.sh:     3:bl bl function foxtrot(){ 
2020/12/25    18:33:02   ./i_dir/file_05.sh:     4:bl bl function foxtrot(){ 
2020/12/25    18:33:00   ./i_dir/file_01.sh:     4:foo function juliet(){ 
2020/12/25    18:32:56   ./i_dir/file_02.sh:     5:foo function charlie(){ 
2020/12/24    18:32:58   ./i_dir/file_02.sh:     7:bla bla function mike(){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, with GNU awk:

```
find "i_dir" -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec gawk -v goodpat="$pattern_GOOD_word" -v badpat="$pattern_BAD_word" '
  BEGIN{cmd = "stat -c %Y "; OFS="\t"}
  $0 ~ badpat {next} 
  $0 ~ goodpat {
    cmd FILENAME | getline mtime;
    close(cmd FILENAME);
    print strftime("%Y/%m/%d\t%H:%M:%S",mtime), FILENAME, FNR ":" $0
  }
' {} \; | sort -r
```

You will need to express `pattern_GOOD_word` and `pattern_BAD_word` as GNU Extended Regular Expressions ex.

```
pattern_GOOD_word="function[[:blank:]]"
pattern_BAD_word="function[[:blank:]]pause"
```